# Request for a tag: Poco-Libraries

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

As I posted a question regarding Poco-libraries (http://pocoproject.org) on StackExchange today, I mistakenly tagged it 'poco' (which relates to "Plain Old CLR Object").

I suggest adding a tag for the poco C++ libraries.

Comment: I added the Poco-Libraries tag. Hope it helps ;-).

Comment: @Gamecat: Me too, thank you. Probably it won't help on my question, but it prevents others to tag it 'poco'.